# html form to flask app route to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I created a basic html site that has a form section to select an image.

```
       <form action="/image" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="img">Select Image:</label>
            <input type="file" id="img" name="image">
            <input id = 'upload' type = "submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

Once in this html you can browse an image file locally and hit the Upload button.

and send this to the route `/image` in flask:

```
import script

@app.route('/image', methods = ['POST'])   
def image():  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        if request.files['image']:
            f = request.files['image'] 
            f.save(f.filename) 

            # This is a python script
            data = script.getvalue(f.filename)
            
            return jsonify(data)
```

The primary issue with this route is that the html form has an `action="/image"` that expects to render a template as well, `return render_template("image.html")` or `return render_template("image.html, info=data")`

But since I am trying to get the data output from route `/image` to be use in javascript I only want to return `return jsonify(data)` so that I can use `d3.json` in javascript as follows:

```
d3.json("/image").then(function(emotion) {

    console.log(emotion)
});
```

So that I can perform some d3 handling.

The issue I have is that if I only return `return jsonify(data)` I get an error because it is expecting a html template and if I try this: `return render_template("image.html, info=data")` then javascript wont be able to hable the data I am passing.

Any suggestions on this it would be greatly appreciate it!!!!

Comment: why you can't just create 2 different routes(`/image-upload` and `/chart-data`)? first will return only `html`, the second - only `json`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar The issue is that the html form requires an action to return an html file. So whenever I hit submit the form it request to refresh an html page and if the route doesnt have a render_template it will fail.

Comment: first of all. as I know `d3.json` works with http `GET`. not `POST`. you can save file using `POST` and read file using `GET`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar can you please provide an example on how to do that? The only way I've used d3.json is just calling the route itself in flask that is returning a jsonify data.

Comment: can you share a tiny example with `js`, `file content` + `jinja template`?